# Attribute Error when scraping a table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, stock, scraper

I'm new here and I'm trying to scrape a website (http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/financialHighlights?symbol=PETR4.SA) and get a table with financial data. I want to transform that table into a 56x6 matrix (all the row subtitles and their respective data, but not the big titles)

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
import string
import bs4 as bs
import requests
import pickle
#   Trying to structure data for calculating Piotroski Score

def get_financial_data(tickers):
    for ticker in tickers:
        resp = requests.get('http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/financialHighlights?symbol='+ticker)
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "lxml")
        dirty = soup.find('div', {'class': 'column1 gridPanel grid8'})
        for row in dirty.findAll('tr'):
            fin_data = row.findAll('td',{'class': 'data'})
            print(fin_data)
    return financial_data

tickers = ['PETR4.SA']

get_financial_data(tickers)
```

This is the kind of response I get, if I make fin_titles only get from td class ='data':

```
[]
[]
[<td class="data">1</td>, <td class="data">69,439.50</td>, <td    class="data">69,439.50</td>, <td class="data">69,439.50</td>, <td class="data">--</td>]
[<td class="data">1</td>, <td class="data">76,729.30</td>, <td class="data">76,729.30</td>, <td class="data">76,729.30</td>, <td class="data">--</td>]
[<td class="data">12</td>, <td class="data">309,740.00</td>, <td class="data">361,640.00</td>, <td class="data">278,991.00</td>, <td class="data">371,363.00</td>]
[<td class="data">12</td>, <td class="data">349,548.00</td>, <td class="data">405,189.00</td>, <td class="data">299,724.00</td>, <td class="data">424,804.00</td>]
```

...

How can I get what's inside those tags and put them into a numbers matrix so I can do math with them? (i.e., calculate the score closest to Piotroski F-Score)

Thank you SO MUCH. I've been trying to do this by hand, instead of using something like Quantopian, which only works with US assets. (as far as I know)

Comment: You use `tag.string` to get what's inside the tag. Does this answer your question, or did you get an `AttributeError` ? Your question does not mention where you get it.

Comment: You can use `td.text` or `td.string` as @Tobias suggested . Then you can use `ast.literal_eval` or try - except blocks to get numeric values